# Convert an array stored as a string, to a proper numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For long and tedious reasons, I have lots of arrays that are stored as strings:

```
tmp = '[[1.0, 3.0, 0.4]\n [3.0, 4.0, -1.0]\n [3.0, 4.0, 0.1]\n [3.0, 4.0, 0.2]]'
```

Now I obviously do not want my arrays as long strings, I want them as proper numpy arrays so I can use them. Consequently, what is a good way to convert the above to:

```
tmp_np = np.array([[1.0, 3.0, 0.4]
                   [3.0, 4.0, -1.0]
                   [3.0, 4.0, 0.1]
                   [3.0, 4.0, 0.2]])
```

such that I can do simple things like `tmp_np.shape = (4,3)` or simple indexing `tmp_np[0,:] = [1.0, 3.0, 0.4]` etc.

Thanks

Comment: Have  you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200353/reading-data-into-numpy-array-from-text-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and a lot of other documentations regard this problem in Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html), if you replace your `\n` characters with `,`:

```
temp_np = np.array(ast.literal_eval(tmp.replace('\n', ',')))
```

Returns:

```
>>> tmp_np
array([[ 1. ,  3. ,  0.4],
       [ 3. ,  4. , -1. ],
       [ 3. ,  4. ,  0.1],
       [ 3. ,  4. ,  0.2]])
```