# How to change a text file into a two dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python

I wanted to change a text file into a two-dimensional numpy array. my text file looks like this if opened.

```
01110111110111010111011101110111010111011111010101110101011101110
01000001000001010001010100010101010000010001010100010101000100010
01110111011111011101010111011101110111110111010111010101110111010
01010000010000010101010001010000000100000000010101010000010101010
01010111110111110101010101010111111101110111110101010111110101010
```

later I want to access every element of the line.
I appreciate anyone with hints:

Comment: If you only need hints refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200353/reading-data-into-numpy-array-from-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
with open(file_path, 'rt') as f:
    result = np.array([[ int(c) for c in line ] for line in f ])
```

Comment: Got this error after running with this code:", line 150, in <module>
    result = np.array([[int(c) for c in line] for line in ff])

Comment: I fixed the error that showed up, thanks for the hint indeed.