# IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5, numpy-ndarray, index-error

I want to bring in a text file through PyQt5 and draw a graph with data values.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('folder.png'), 'Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Text.txt')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.show)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setWindowTitle('File Dialog')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', './')

        if fname[0]:
            f = open(fname[0], 'r')


            with f:
                data = f.read()
                data2=np.array(data)
                x=data2[1:,0]
                y=data2[1:,1]

                plt.plot(x,y)
                plt.show()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Text file photo.

This is the error that appears:

```
x=data2[1:,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Comment: did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20200353/10197418) question?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `numpy`, you don't need to write your own code to load data from files. Use the `numpy` functions to do this for you.

In `show()`, I would recommend to change the code like this:

```
data = np.loadtxt(fname[0], skiprows=1)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer showed you how to do this correctly, so I'll instead explain what went wrong in your code.

In `data = f.read()`, the file is stored as a string instead of an array. If you inspect it, you would see something like `x    y     \n1    2    \n`, with `\n` being the newline character. Therefore, `data2 = np.array(data)` ends up creating a numpy array containing a single string.

Because your array only has a single item, it has 0 dimensions instead of the two dimensions that you expected.